# Цикл при загрузке файла csv

Tags: php

Добрый день! Подскажите, как можно при загрузке файла csv в цикле собрать массив таким образом что бы пустые строки относились к заполненным.

```
   while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";")) != FALSE){
   }
```

Например $row[2] и $row[3] пустое то к строке  ( Бологое- + Московское-26, + Лихославль-96 )

```
     $row[0]              ; $row[1];$row[2]; $row[3];$row[4]           ;$row[5]
 Академическая       Б 3  ;  Окт   ; 241   ; 30     ;Бологое-          ;062900
                          ;        ;       ;        ;Московское-26,    ;
                          ;        ;       ;        ;Лихославль-96     ;
```

и в результате получилось

```
Академическая  Б 3;Окт; 241;30;Бологое-Московское-26,Лихославль-96;062900
```

Comment: А почему бы просто не пропускать, если строка пустая?

Comment: Дело в том что пустые строки относиться к верхней строчки и в ней есть инфа но не во всех, было бы не проблема если бы не было 25 000к строк

Comment: а если row[0] не пустое, а остальные - пустое ?